# Reducing duplicate substrings in yml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a YML file in a spring boot project and it has some properties like:

```
core:
  endpoint:
    selene:
     documentarchive: kafka:selene-events-document-archive?brokers=kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31090,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31091,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31092,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31093&groupId=documentArchive|seda:selene-events-document-archive?concurrentConsumers=5&multipleConsumers=true
```

There are other properties at the same level as `documentarchive` and all of them have the substring `brokers=....:31093` common. I want to remove this duplicacy.

**Things I have tried:**
I found that I can create a variable in yml file like:

```
define: &brokers 'kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31090,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31091,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31092,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31093'
```

I could access this variable in spring boot if I define a property like `testprop: *brokers`  but the documentArchive property has this value used in between which will require concatenation. I am not sure if there is a way to do this in YML , or spring boot or maybe include some library that could aid in it.
Any suggestions, or alternatives?

An alternative approach I can think of is to define variable like this in yml: `define: &brokers 'kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31090,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31091,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31092,kafka-qa.ops.k8s.use1.com:31093'`
and change the other properties in yml to :

```
 core:
      endpoint:
        selene:
         documentarchive: kafka:selene-events-document-archive?brokers={brokers}&groupId=documentArchive|seda:selene-events-document-archive?concurrentConsumers=5&multipleConsumers=true
```

Now when I read the `core.endpoint.selene.documentarchive` in springboot I can replace the broker's value {brokers} with the actual value, which is also read from the YML file.  This does seem to be a clumsy way to achieve this. Doesn't seem preferable.

Comment: @tobifasc that's in yml file